# python calculator indentation error (cant seem to get the program working)

Tags: python, calculator, indentation

I just started python yesterday so I was trying to make this python code to make a calculator that adds, multiplies, divides, and subtracts. When I started testing the code just wasn't working even though I did similar things and to me, the code looked right this is the code:

```
op =input("which operation would you like to use (type m for multiply d for divide s for subtract a for addition): ")
first_number =float(input("please enter your first number: "))
second_number =float(input("please enter your second number: "))
if op.upper()=="m" or op.lower()=="m":
    print("multiply")
   elif op.upper()=="d" or op.lower()=="d":
       print("divide")
   elif op.upper()=="s" or op.lower()=="s":
       print("subtract")
   elif op.upper()=="a" or op.lower()=="a":
       print("addition")
else:print("the operation you entered is not available")
```

I was expecting it to take input and based on this it would know what operation I wanted to make but this is the error I got:

```
elif op.upper()=="d" or op.lower()=="d":
                                            ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong, your elifs are indented wrong.  Those lines should be in line with the if statement, with the print statement indented below each

Comment: That line(6 th) has only 3 spaces. It should be 4 spaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should resolve the indentation error.

```
op =input("which operation would you like to use (type m for multiply d for divide s for subtract a for addition): ")
first_number =float(input("please enter your first number: "))
second_number =float(input("please enter your second number: "))
if op.upper()=="m" or op.lower()=="m":
    print("multiply")
elif op.upper()=="d" or op.lower()=="d":
       print("divide")
elif op.upper()=="s" or op.lower()=="s":
       print("subtract")
elif op.upper()=="a" or op.lower()=="a":
       print("addition")
else:
    print("the operation you entered is not available")
```

Comment: well thank you now thinking about it that's why it's called an indentation error 

Comment: The statements in `elif` branches should be alilgned with `if` indentation (although this doesn't seem to be an error).

Answer (score -1):

It should look like this:

```
op =input("which operation would you like to use (type m for multiply d for divide s for subtract a for addition): ")
first_number =float(input("please enter your first number: "))
second_number =float(input("please enter your second number: "))
if op.upper()=="m" or op.lower()=="m":
    print("multiply")
elif op.upper()=="d" or op.lower()=="d":
    print("divide")
elif op.upper()=="s" or op.lower()=="s":
    print("subtract")
elif op.upper()=="a" or op.lower()=="a":
    print("addition")
else:
    print("the operation you entered is not available")
```

Comment: thank you i really didn't think it was that simple❤